# .sortable() removing css of my page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using .sortable funciton on my page. 
The issue is that It is also removing a particular .css class from my page. 
Does any1 has any idea on how to prevent .sortable() from removing the css?

Following is the code part for applying sortable to my content

```
function makeSortable() {

    $('.column').sortable();
    $(".column").sortable("option", "connectWith", ".column");
    $(".column").sortable("option", "handle", ".moveHeader");
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in Jquery before this function is called a particular css is shown applied to my content. The moment control passes

```
$('.column').sortable();
```

The css seems to be gone.

Comment: give some code to get better idea!!!!

Comment: What css class is being removed?

Comment: I have a css named google.js.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Much possible that the sortable function is overriding the css values that you have defined in the google.js.css file. have a check on that.